# Java regular expression replace issue

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url="http://a.b.com/m/test/index";
        System.out.println(url.replaceAll("^.*?((?<!/)(?:/)(?!/))", ""));
    }
}
```

The system print is: `m/test/index`.
But in my mind it should print is:`/m/test/index`. Somebody give some reason?

Comment: Use URI/URL class to process them. Don't play around with regular expression in such case.

Comment: While your comment is generally true, a) that's not what the question is about, and b) someone has to write those URL processors. See Asimov's short story "Profession".

Comment: @MadPhysicist: This is Java. Use the class library. You don't even have to write the class yourself.

Comment: Again, I don't disagree. This question is about regex, not specifically URL. The "http" in the string is incidental.

Comment: On a side note, is there a reason for using `(?:/)` in the middle instead of just `/`?

Comment: @Cinnam   In my thinking, no capture group is not replaced which is replaced in fact.

Comment: `^.*?((?<!/)(?=/)(?!//))` See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM3vY6/1)

Comment: `(?:/)` will matched the `/` before `m`,so we should use `(?=/)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex reads "As few characters as possible up to and including the first slash that is neither preceded nor followed by a slash". The slash itself is clearly included in the regex. The fact that it is in a non-capturing group does not mean that it is not part of the match.